# App crashing when trying to use VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

I just started messing with android dev and I am trying to simply play a video file that is on the web somewhere. My Main.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/buttonText" android:onClick="clickHandler"></Button>
    <VideoView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/MyVideoView"></VideoView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my java file looks like this:
        package com.dop.videoTest;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoTest extends Activity {
    private String path = "http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
    private VideoView mVideoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void clickHandler(View view)
    {
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.MyVideoView);

        if (path == "") {
            Toast.makeText(
                    VideoTest.this,
                    "Please edit VideoViewDemo Activity, and set path"
                            + " variable to your media file URL/path",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(path);
            mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
            mVideoView.requestFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

so when I click my button, it just says "The application Video Test has stopped unexpectedly. Please Try Again."

any idea?

Comment: To compare strings use equals(`path.equals("")`), not `path == ""`

Comment: doing == works fine. Besides that won't fix the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path in your code is

```
private String path = "http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";
```

The VideoView will need internet access for this. 
Most probably you did not set the internet permission in the manifest. 
One of the reason why this happens is when your application tries to access something which needs explicit permission statement in the manifest.

The internet permission can be set as:

```
< uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Check this link:
[Android Manifest Documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html)

Comment: You are right, adding that line in fact made the error go away and the video now plays. Why does eclipse not tell you such a thing? I would have never guessed that to be the reason.

Comment: Well, android support in eclipse is done by a separate plugin developed by android team of google(As much as i know). So its their part..should not blame eclipse for that. Im not sure how easy is for the android developers to tell you of such errors but still android development support is not yet any close to matured phase..but they will i believe.

Comment: Gotcha...do you know of a way to do a trace or echo in java so it appears in the eclipse console?

Comment: You can use LogCat for this. [Check this lik](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2011/01/16/android-activity-life-cyclelogcat-and-exception-handling/)